# Expresso store paypal fields

Tags: add-on, expresso-store, paypal-express-checkout

I am testing my first install of Store in a Paypal sandbox. The one issue i would like to fix is that the billing details are not pulled through from the site. Only the email address, name and telephone are carried through. As it is a bit annoying to have to type them again, can these not also be populated in PayPal?

Comment: You'll need to provide more details. Which PayPal service are you using specifically? What is the related code for your billing fields? What have you tried already in your testing? Are the billing fields printing out in the EE templates when you test that?

Comment: Which other billing fields are you expecting it to pull through? Since you won't be able to comment until you have more rep on this site, please update your question with the extra details :)

Comment: Closing as this question has not been updated in a reasonable amount of time and cannot be answered without more details.